# Recover data from two RAID 0 drives in Fedora or Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, fedora, data-recovery, raid-0

I have an external drive from WD which consists of two separate 3.5" discs which have been used in RAID 0 mode. Unfortunately, a while ago I fed the drive with to high voltage which probably fried the circuts of the internal mother board (I'm working under the assumption at the discs themselves are intact here).

Now, I've opened up the plastic casing and removed the actual hard discs, which I have put into a regular computer in the two hard drive slots. I'm using the latest version of Fedora on this computer (which I have to run from a CD since my hard disc slots are occupied by the drives I'm trying to recover). I could also switch to Ubuntu if necessary.

How should I go about from here to recover the data (again, assuming that the drives are intact)? The drives does not just show up Nautilus so I guess I'll have to dig a little deeper to find something.

Update: After looking around a little on Stack Exchange I found the following thread ([Raid 0 - what happens with the data when hdds plugged into another motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/84071/raid-0-what-happens-with-the-data-when-hdds-plugged-into-another-motherboard)), meaning it might not be possible for me to do what I wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any first hand experience with this. Fedora appears to use the mdadm utility to manage raids for the utility to manage a raid it needs to be setup in the mdadm.conf file. In theory you should be able to add the two hard drives to the conf in the proper order as existing and that should allow you to use fedora to access them ... remember this is in theory I have never had to do this.

Here is the man page for the mdadm.conf
[mdadm.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/mdadm.conf)

Recovering Raids in Fedora Walkthrough
[Walkthrough](http://dailypackage.fedorabook.com/index.php?/archives/160-System-Recovery-Week-Recovering-RAID-Devices.html)