# Is it possible to migrate a boot RAID volume from an older motherboard to a newer one?

Tags: windows, ssd, raid, raid-0, hardware-raid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raid 0 - what happens with the data when hdds plugged into another motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/84071/raid-0-what-happens-with-the-data-when-hdds-plugged-into-another-motherboard)

### Background info

I am going to upgrade my current setup from an X58 to an X79 and I have 2 RAID 0 volumes on the current setup. These are both sat up through the motherboard (i.e. they are hardware fake-RAID). One controller is Marvell and the other one Intel. We are talking specifically an [ASUS Rampage III Extreme](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1366/Rampage_III_Extreme/).

### The question

Does taking the RAIDed SSDs from my current setup, putting them into the new setup and configuring them as RAID volumes mean losing all data or does the new motherboard understand that the discs actually already are RAIDed and just start reading data from them like nothing has happened?

If not, what do I have to do in order to be able to cleanly migrate my setup? I would not like to be forced to reinstall windows and my applications.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the RAID controllers are similar (at least by the same manufacturer) then there's a good chance the new controller will recognize the RAID configuration already present on the disks, or will, once you configure the new controller with similar settings (and don't initialize the array).

You're more likely to run into driver incompatibility problems in Windows itself once you get it to boot.

IMO, get a backup drive, do a full system backup and restore to the new hardware.  NTBackup (ASR) and Windows Backup (System Image) both offer this, depending on your version of Windows.

It's the cleanest way to ensure you're kernel-level drivers (like RAID controller drivers) are right.  Plus if things muff-up during migration, you have a backup to try again.

Comment: The driver compitability shouldn't be such a big problem because in my experience windows recognizes everything and installs the correct drivers upon reboot or whatever. For instance when I first got my current setup I just popped the HDD from my old laptop and booted up without any problems. But then again all these scenarios I've been in have been intel to intel and nvidia to nvidia. Not like AMD to Intel, that _COULD_ be a problem.. Gonna accept the answer when I assemble the new computer..

Comment: @Akke Windows has to recognise the boot volume the first time though.